# Deleted Ubuntu 20 alongside windows 10 and unable to install again

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu 20 alongside Windows 10, then removed Ubuntu and grub issues were also solved, now I am unable to install Ubuntu 20 again.

I am installing through USB and a black screen comes with some lines.

[image: error message]

It is when I am booting the installer. Ubuntu is not installed on my system.

Comment: what is hashes?

Comment: See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM &
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes & Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: Please see the image i have uploaded here to solve my problem. @oldfred

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Many need UEFI update, change from RAID or Intel RST to AHCI. Some need boot parameters. And Windows fast start up off. Also if UEFI updated, you may have to redo some UEFI settings you changed.

Comment: intel i3 7th generation, nanotech motherboard, 8GB RAM, 1 TB hard disk, 120 GB SSD, No additional graphic cards

Comment: actually I installed a day before Ubuntu alongside windows 10. Ubuntu was working little bit slow. Then I uninstalled ubuntu but grub issue was there due to which I was unable to use windows...then  I made windows bootable file and then repair my computer....then troubleshoot, and command prompt...and wrote these commands: bootrec.exe /FixMbr and then enter...again bootrec.exe /FixBoot and enter....and then windows was loading properly....Now again I am trying to install the same iso file but this image comes..that I have uploaded here.

Comment: Did a Windows update, turn fast start up back on? Have you updated UEFI? Often SSD also need firmware updates. There are many questions & answers on slow boot or slow system, if that is issue, best to review those as reinstall may not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your installer is corrupt.

1. Re-download the installer .iso
2. [Check the hash](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu) to verify a good download
3. Re-make the install USB with the verified .iso.

Comment: please see the photo.. I have uploaded the photo I get during booting@user535733

Comment: Still I could not solve my problem by the above suggestions